# MSTest time outs with multi-threading integration tests

Tags: asynchronous, timeout, unity-container, mstest

In our project, we have a couple of thousand unit tests. Some of them are integration tests which require a larger setup and which also use multi-threading / asynchronous parts, as well as unity for setting up the objects.

These integration tests usually run pretty smoothly, but in some instances, when ALL tests in the solution (~2.5k) are executed, the asynchronous components for seem to run into deadlock for some reason. (Test aborted due to timeout)

I've searched up and down my code for hours, but I couldn't find any reason why a deadlock could occur.

Btw, we use polling for waiting for re-synchronizing the threads:

```
var foo = new SomethingThatIsModifiedByTheAsyncThreads();
this.SetupEverything();
this.AsyncComponentX.StartSomething(foo);

// wait for completion
while (foo.State != fooStates.AllDone)
{
Thread.Sleep(10);
}

// check output
Assert.IsTrue(this.CheckThatAllIsRight(foo));
```

This isn't the nicest way to do it, but I don't think that this is the problem (other thoughts?).. so, to me it seems that the the asynchronous stuff simply does not complete, it doesn't set set foo.State to AllDone. But how can that be? Why does this only occur when I **run** (not Debug) a large number of tests? I suspect that MSTest kind of messes up something with the threads (there are four of them), not letting them run. (Btw, the asynch stuff runs as special asynch modules which work as a message queue with a single worker/messageconsumer thread each. But these classes appear to be tried and true.)

It's also quite hard to figure out what's going on in there, I'm working on extending logging in the asynchronous parts. Butwell, I still have no idea where the problem may lie, or how to reproduce the issue without running all tests.. any pointers? :/
I've read about some threading issues with MSTest.. are there some special things to consider?